# Hide rails atom feed from everyone except feedburner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created an atom feed for my rails app but I would like users to subscribe via feedburner. I would like to hide the page from everyone except feedburner.

I've found a similar question but the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133066/how-to-hide-rss-page-from-everyone-except-feedburner) seemed specific to php. Could someone help achieve this this in rails? Thanks

My route for the feed is "/feed"

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make sense to do this on the web server level? I'd assume that FeedBurner uses a UserAgent you can match against, so only allow `/feed` for that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UserAgents how would I implement that? Do you know of any good posts? I've researched and haven't found anything explaining how to do this.

Comment: What web server are you using? For Apache there's a bit of discussion here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3719870.htm BTW: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: There you go: http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/details/127228/index.html. Please upvote/accept if this was helpful.

Comment: I think it's thin web server, I've deployed with heroku

Answer (score 0):

You can deny access by the USER_AGENT field from the HTTP Header like Michael told but you can also match against a range of IP-adresses which is quiet more secure if google provies the range. They did it for their web crawling bot (in their webmaster blog) so you might search the FAQs and documentation of feedburner for an address range.